# How to limit products selection for a bundle product in Magento?

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product

My customer wants to offer a "kit" with only 2 products/items and customers could select only 2 products between the available ones, and also pick a color and size per product. I couldn't think how to achieve that in Magento. As an alternative option, we could have a generic kit/bundle and users should be able to type on a comment box on the checkout page which SKU's to be delivered with their respective sizes and colors.

Anyone has some thoughts to do the magic??

Comment: Can this one suit your needs? https://www.wizkunde.nl/magento-2-configurable-bundle.html

Comment: Pretty much, except by the fact that I use Magento 1.9 and have no more budget for that. Actually I would like to know if there is some workaround using Magento native options, which would be our best choice.

Comment: There are M1 equivalent. But seems doesn't fit your price tag: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-bundle.html